# Релизы монорепозитория (монорепы)

Tags: git, контроль-версий, версионирование, версионность

Каким образом Вы осуществляете релизы? Так, если у нас множество репозиториев, тогда релизы осуществляются каждым репозиторием условно независимо. Я всегда делаю это с помощью тегов. Если же у нас есть монорепозиторий, тогда система тегов перестаёт работать, так как создание нового тега эквивалентно созданию релиза всей системы. Как быть?

В данном вопросе я говорю про микросервисную архитектуру. В такие микросервисы входит как фронтэнд, так и бэкэнд.

Comment: Не держите всё в одном репозитории.

Comment: @0andriy я понимаю. Но мой вопрос именно про это. Так складывается ситуация.

Comment: Специально для таких целей есть утилита _repo_, то есть вы сами себя загоняете в неразрешимую ситуацию.

Comment: @0andriy дайте на неё ссылку пожалуйста. Я нашёл несколько таких утилит

Comment: Та, которой пользуется Android. https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/

Comment: @0andriy что мне с ней делать, если мой проект на golang и python

Comment: Разбить ваш репозиторий на проекты, потом объединить их в общий с помощью манифеста. В общем, разбирайтесь,

Comment: @0andriy классный совет. Спасибо, воспользуюсь! Особенно понравилось про разбирайтесь. Учту.